# How does an organizational user log into an add-in

Tags: ms-word, office-js

The [Microsoft docs state that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/store/implement-licensing-for-add-in-services#step-2-create-a-licensing-database)

> To sell Office Add-ins to organizations, you need to create a licensing database. This is necessary because:
>
> - ...
> - Centralized deployment does not allow users to buy add-ins from AppSource and deploy them. AppSource paid add-ins today only work with personal identities (Microsoft accounts), ***not work or school accounts.***

So, if I want an organization to adopt my Office Add-in I have to handle the licensing workflow myself. This raises a few questions that the docs don't answer.

An organizational user will not have an AppSource (AS) token. Instead, how do I authenticate an org user if the user is not logged in to Office? My add-in should implement a log on screen  or single sign-on (SSO)? How do you log a Microsoft user on without single sign-on? They input their username/password and I send this to Microsoft Graph? That doesn't sound secure at all (the fact that I have their Office credentials, that is).

I guess I'm confused about the authentication and authorization workflow of an add-in that is intended for organizational license. Can anyone point me to a working example or provide more information, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have multiple, related questions. I don't know if this will answer them all.

Users can log into Office with either a Microsoft Account or a work-or-school account. There is a single sign-on system, that is *currently in preview*, that enables you to leverage this same sign-on credential (including a work-or-school credential) for your application. For an overview of the system, see [SSO in Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins).

Like any web application, you could also of course, implement your own backend user tables with user names, encrypted passwords, user permissions, and license status.

Finally, your web application could leverage one of the social identity providers such as Facebook or Microsoft Account. In the case of Microsoft Account, if you don't use the SSO system, then users would have to login to the MS account a second time, even if they are already logged into Office with that account.

Comment: I read the _in preview_ description for SSO. What does that mean, exactly? A limited rollout, not to be used in production?

Comment: "Preview" basically means "beta". You need Office 2016, Version 1708, build 8424.nnnn or later (the Office 365 subscription version, sometimes called “Click to Run”). We don't recommend that you use it in a production add-in while it is in preview.

Comment: Hmmm. What should be used instead?

Comment: If we don't use SSO, do we have to implement user registration (with a new username/pw, ie not their Microsoft account)?

Comment: @seebiscuit For a production add-in, I think you should use one of the options in the last two paragraphs of my answer. My interpretation of the rule is that you can use Microsoft Account for the authentication, but you will need your own user table for license status. Your backend would look up the user using something from his MS Account credentials/profile as the lookup key.

Comment: Makes sense. I believe that I need to stick with a MS Account login, so that I can have access to the user's organizational tenant ID, for enterprise license. Makes sense?

Comment: Any idea when SSO will be out of Preview?